# API error when installing programs following apt-get install

Tags: linux, api, lua, fedora

I am having problems when typing the following code in Fedora Linux shell:

```
[root@localhost KDVDRam]# apt-get install kdvdramtools-0.4
Reading Package Lists... Done
Building Dependency Tree... Done
PANIC: unprotected error in call to Lua API (attempt to index a nil value)
Aborted (core dumped)
[root@localhost KDVDRam]# sudo apt-get install kdvdramtools-0.4
BDB2053 Freeing read locks for locker 0xae4: 404/140312489400384
BDB2053 Freeing read locks for locker 0xae5: 404/140312489400384
Reading Package Lists... Done
Building Dependency Tree... Done
PANIC: unprotected error in call to Lua API (attempt to index a nil value)
```

Can anybody help me what went wrong and how to solve this?
JohnDBCT

Comment: `apt-get` on Fedora? That sounds like the first problem. Fedora uses `yum` for the analogous task.

Comment: hello BRPocock , that infact was the problem even at my side . Solved it by using yum insted of apt-get

Answer (score 1):

`apt-get` on fedora finds some of the packages that `yum` always says nothing to do because no such package... 
also `apt-cache` search has proven invaluable to me so why not be able to have the universality of both? and in fact if I have the ability to install `Fink` or `Fink Commander` on my fedora so it shall be done!